# Rotating Bezier Curve Handles not working

Tags: unity-game-engine

I created a bezier curve that is drawn with handles. When I rotate the container game object the curve rotates but the anchor point and control point handles don't rotate. I suspect the problem is coming from the following lines of code in my `PathEditor` class. How can I fix this rotation issue?

If needed, please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50788120/how-to-make-individual-anchor-points-of-bezier-continuous-or-non-continuous) for the other classes linked to the PathEditor, I decided not to put them here to keep the question tidy.

Suspected lines within PathEditor `Draw()` method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < path.NumPoints; i++)
    {
        Vector2 newPos = Handles.FreeMoveHandle(path[i], Quaternion.identity, .1f, Vector2.zero, Handles.CylinderHandleCap);
        if (path[i] != newPos)
        {
            Undo.RecordObject(creator, "Move point");
            path.MovePoint(i, newPos);
        }
    }
```

PathEditor:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(PathCreator))]
public class PathEditor : Editor {

PathCreator creator;
Path path;

public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{
    base.OnInspectorGUI();
    EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();

    bool continuousControlPoints = GUILayout.Toggle(path.isContinuous, "Set Continuous Control Points");
    if (continuousControlPoints != path.isContinuous)
    {
        Undo.RecordObject(creator, "Toggle set continuous controls");
        path.isContinuous = continuousControlPoints;
    }

    if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
    {
        SceneView.RepaintAll();
    }
}

void OnSceneGUI()
{
    Input();
    Draw();
}

void Input()
 {
    Event guiEvent = Event.current;
    Vector2 mousePos = HandleUtility.GUIPointToWorldRay(guiEvent.mousePosition).origin;

    if (guiEvent.type == EventType.MouseDown && guiEvent.button == 0 && guiEvent.shift)
    {
        Undo.RecordObject(creator, "Add segment");
        path.AddSegment(mousePos);
    }
}

void Draw()
{

     Transform handleTransform = creator.transform;
    Quaternion handleRotation = Tools.pivotRotation == PivotRotation.Local ?
        handleTransform.rotation : Quaternion.identity;

    for (int i = 0; i < path.NumSegments; i++)
    {
        Vector2[] points = path.GetPointsInSegment(i);
        Handles.color = Color.black;

        Vector2 p0 = handleTransform.TransformPoint(points[0]);
        Vector2 p1 = handleTransform.TransformPoint(points[1]);
        Vector2 p2 = handleTransform.TransformPoint(points[2]);
        Vector2 p3 = handleTransform.TransformPoint(points[3]);

        Handles.DrawLine(p1, p0);
        Handles.DrawLine(p2, p3);
        Handles.DrawBezier(p0, p3, p1, p2, Color.green, null, 2);

    }


    Handles.color = Color.red;
    for (int i = 0; i < path.NumPoints; i++)
    {
        Vector2 newPos = Handles.FreeMoveHandle(path[i], Quaternion.identity, .1f, Vector2.zero, Handles.CylinderHandleCap);
        if (path[i] != newPos)
        {
            Undo.RecordObject(creator, "Move point");
            path.MovePoint(i, newPos);
        }
    }
}

void OnEnable()
{
    creator = (PathCreator)target;
    if (creator.path == null)
    {
        creator.CreatePath();
    }
    path = creator.path;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are storing the points values in world coordinates. When you transform your object, those points are not aware of that and keep drawing on the same places.

Instead, store points in local coordinates and apply matrix transformation each time you draw.

**EDIT** do the following steps to get it working:

1. Treat all points in `Path` as local coordinates (i.e. relative to the gameObject itself)
2. In `PathEditor`, you should use the target's `transform` component to apply a transformation anytime you want to set values from path to the scene. For example, in the `Input` method, you should correct the mouse position like that:

   mousePos = creator.transform.InverseTransformPoint(mousePos);

In your `Draw` method, you are actualy calculating the correct `handleTrasform` matrix and the quaternion `handleRotation`, but you are not applying the them:

```
Vector2 newPos = Handles.FreeMoveHandle(path[i], Quaternion.identity, .1f, Vector2.zero, Handles.CylinderHandleCap);
```

Should be:

```
var pos = handleTransform.InverseTransformPoint(path[i]);
Vector2 newPos = Handles.FreeMoveHandle(pos, handleRotation, .1f, Vector2.zero, Handles.CylinderHandleCap);
```

You also could, instead, set the `Handles.matrix` at the start of the method and the scales will be handled automatically.

```
Handles.matrix = creator.transform.localToWorldMatrix;
```

Comment: Please include an example on how to do so related to the code I provided in the question.

Comment: Without the code in Path and PathCreator it would be hard

Comment: Actually I added a link to another question I asked that has the Path and PathCreator code, but anyway here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50788120/how-to-make-individual-anchor-points-of-bezier-continuous-or-non-continuous

Comment: Yeah, I answered that. I remember now

Comment: Please, I thought you were updating your answer. I still haven't been able to get this to work

Comment: I'll be back in this soon, I got busy IRL

Comment: Okay, this is just a gentle reminder :). The linked questions is also on a bounty that will expire soon

Comment: Edited here too to be more specific.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to accept your answer for this. Thanks