# What sort of inline function is this and how does it work?

Tags: c#

I am making an NPC path tool in Unity and I have borrowed some functionality from this other post on stack overflow ([How to make individual anchor points of bezier continuous or non-continuous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50788120/how-to-make-individual-anchor-points-of-bezier-continuous-or-non-continuous)).

I have not copied or repurposed anything that I could not have made myself, with the only exception being this line (at the bottom of the post), that unfortunately the entire program is dependent upon.

I understand that this is some kind of inline function declaration/definition, but I do not understand how it works. I think that the end result is a list of ControlPoint's being generated but I am not entirely sure.

I would not be that bothered but I am constantly getting an index out of bounds error from a loop in another class and the error code is pointing to this line. I am sure that I would be able to solve it if I could understand this line and deconstruct it. I suspect that it's some kind of C# specific ternary operator but I've never seen it before and although I've tried, I have no idea what to google or where to find the appropriate documentation to explain it.

So in essence I am asking for an explanation of the syntactic sugar on this specific line of code that this person has used so that I am able to deconstruct this line of code and fix the issue in my program.

Any help is appreciated, cheers!

(Original code sample):

```
public ControlPoint this[int i] { get { return points[(loop && i == points.Count) ? 0 : i]; } }
```

(ControlPoint is a seperate class used to define the properties and methods of an anchor point and the tangent points on a bezier curve)

(points is a list of ControlPoints)

(loop is a boolean variable that defines whether the path is closed or not)

Edit: Looks like the reason I didn't understand was not just because I'm not overly familar with ternary operators, it was because this person used an indexer/smart array, which is something I have never come across before. I'm going to remove that as I personally think it's overcomplicating things but here is the *fully* deconstructed indexer (without any ternary operators):

```
public ControlPoint this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            if (loop && i == points.Count)
            {
                return points[0];
            }
            else
            {
                return points[i];
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: What if i > points.Count? It looks like it still returns i which possibly goes awry.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Benefits of using the conditional ?: (ternary) operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312786/benefits-of-using-the-conditional-ternary-operator)

Comment: It is an [`Indexed Property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/) with no `set`

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I needed to know. Never heard of indexed properties before so now I can read up on them and fix the issue. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the verbose version:

```
if ((loop) && (i == points.Count))
{
    return points[0];
}
else
{
    return points[i];
}
```

It seems to be "looping" the array by returning the first element if you ask for the element *after* the last one. Meaning if the array has 10 elements (0 through 9) and you ask for element 10, it will "loop" and return the first element.

A "safer" alternative (orthogonal to your question) would be to use the modulo (`%`) operator to enable "looping" (more commonly known as [Circular Buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) ):

```
if (loop))
{
    return points[i % points.Count];
}
else
{
    return points[i];
}
```

or just

```
return points[loop ? (i % points.Count) : i];
```

Comment: FWIW, I might simplify the whole thing to `i % points.Count`, since this would continue to work for a hypothetical 11th iteration and beyond.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I had actually drafted that - but didn't want to complicate the actual question regarding the conditional operator.