# Is there maximum number of meshes in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to upload point cloud in unity C#.
Because there is no element that draws point directly, I create a cube for each point of point cloud.

So, For n points in point cloud, 8n vertices (because it is cube), 12 meshes exist for my code.

- A mesh = 3 index --> a cube : 12 meshes --> 3*12 index (var name : triangles)
- point XYZ are saved in PointList : List < Vector3 >
- each points has color in ColorList : List< Vector3 >

I checked all vertices and meshes have correct values, and drawing points (cubes) works well.

However there is a problem. The original point cloud has 1412765 points(image1). And the number of vertices is same to it. But! If I try to draw all of them, maybe some of them are not drawn. (image2. I guess around 10000 cubes is the maximum.)

What's the problem?
[image]

[image]

```
    float resolution = 2.5f;
    int pointSize = PointList.Count;
    MeshFilter mf = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
    Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
    mf.mesh = mesh;
    Vector3[] vertices;
    vertices = new Vector3[pointSize * 8];
    for (int i = 0; i < pointSize; i++)
    {
        float x = PointList[i].x;
        float y = PointList[i].y;
        float z = PointList[i].z;
        vertices[i * 8 + 0] = new Vector3(x - resolution, y - resolution, z - resolution);
        vertices[i * 8 + 1] = new Vector3(x + resolution, y - resolution, z - resolution);
        vertices[i * 8 + 2] = new Vector3(x + resolution, y + resolution, z - resolution);
        vertices[i * 8 + 3] = new Vector3(x - resolution, y + resolution, z - resolution);
        vertices[i * 8 + 4] = new Vector3(x - resolution, y + resolution, z + resolution);
        vertices[i * 8 + 5] = new Vector3(x + resolution, y + resolution, z + resolution);
        vertices[i * 8 + 6] = new Vector3(x + resolution, y - resolution, z + resolution);
        vertices[i * 8 + 7] = new Vector3(x - resolution, y - resolution, z + resolution);
    }

    mesh.vertices = vertices;

    int[] triangles;
    triangles = new int[pointSize * 12 * 3];

    triangles[0] = 0;
    triangles[1] = 2;
    triangles[2] = 1;
    triangles[3] = 0;
    triangles[4] = 3;
    triangles[5] = 2;

    triangles[6] = 2;
    triangles[7] = 3;
    triangles[8] = 4;
    triangles[9] = 2;
    triangles[10] = 4;
    triangles[11] = 5;

    triangles[12] = 1;
    triangles[13] = 2;
    triangles[14] = 5;
    triangles[15] = 1;
    triangles[16] = 5;
    triangles[17] = 6;

    triangles[18] = 0;
    triangles[19] = 7;
    triangles[20] = 4;
    triangles[21] = 0;
    triangles[22] = 4;
    triangles[23] = 3;

    triangles[24] = 5;
    triangles[25] = 4;
    triangles[26] = 7;
    triangles[27] = 5;
    triangles[28] = 7;
    triangles[29] = 6;

    triangles[30] = 0;
    triangles[31] = 6;
    triangles[32] = 7;
    triangles[33] = 0;
    triangles[34] = 1;
    triangles[35] = 6;

    for (int i = 1; i < pointSize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 36; j++)
        {
            int val = triangles[j] + 8 * i;
            triangles[i * 36 + j] = triangles[j] + 8 * i;
        }
    }
    mesh.triangles = triangles;

    Color32[] colors = new Color32[mesh.vertices.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < pointSize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            Color32 newColor = new Color32(
            (byte)ColorList[i].x,
            (byte)ColorList[i].y,
            (byte)ColorList[i].z,
            255);
            colors[i * 8 + j] = newColor;
        }
    }

    mesh.colors32 = colors;

    Debug.Log("points : " + PointList.Count);
    Debug.Log("vertices  (point*8): " + mesh.vertices.Length);
    Debug.Log("triangles (point*36): " + mesh.triangles.Length);
    Debug.Log("colors (points*8): " + mesh.colors32.Length);
}
```

Comment: did you check the profiler? Maybe you are running out of memory?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I checked it. But I guess it's sufficient to run it Actually my computer has 64GB memory and 2080Ti 11GB GPU. Most of memory are not used when I run my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an anser!!!!

the maximum number of vertices is 65535 when using mesh!!!

Adding just one line can solve this problem

```
 mesh.indexFormat = UnityEngine.Rendering.IndexFormat.UInt32;
```

[How to use meshes with more than 64k vertices in Unity 2018.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50433894/how-to-use-meshes-with-more-than-64k-vertices-in-unity-2018-1)