# What is polygon count limitation for AR applications?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I am on a AR project (with Unity3D and ARCore) in which we are having a very huge area to track. For that we first developed a demo application which worked very well. Then later started developing in large area (600 meter * 600 meter) and a polygon count of 30M triangles. When I built the application all the assets in the scene became very tiny, real time scaling objects are turned to toy size. The same application in VR went very well.

I wanted to know are there any polygon count or area limitations in AR? If so is there any option to create a miniature area with ant camera.

Comment: The scaling of objects has little to do with the amount of triangles or a limitation to it. To the limitations: You can add as many verts and triangles as your CPU/GPU does manage to render within your target frame-rate .. afaik individual meshes in Unity have a [certain limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50433894/how-to-use-meshes-with-more-than-64k-vertices-in-unity-2018-1) .. but there is no limit to individual meshes in a Scene ;)

Comment: you are saying you ported whole VR version to AR???

Comment: yeah. we have done this in VR. Now we want to do the same in AR.

Answer (score 4):

There is no strict limitation on the number of polygons in any AR scene. However, as a general rule, a seasoned developer will not create AR app containing more than **`100K`** polygons (be aware that Apple Vision Pro's app could potentially bypass this limitation but within reason). This is true for any modern framework, be it ARCore, ARKit, Vuforia, RealityKit, or MRTK. **`30M`** polygons is unacceptable amount for robust AR app. Your AR app not only renders 3D geometry with textures and animation but also must track a real world environment and anchors at 60 fps. It's quite heavy burden.

Read [Optimize Model Geometry and Transparency](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/adding_visual_effects_in_ar_quick_look_and_realitykit) section in Apple's article.

Comment: Hey, Built the application with same 30M polygon count with reasonable 60fps. Will release soon.

Comment: If 30M polycount in AR app is an `end in itself` – congrats))