# Why my Triangles starts overlapping when terrainSize too high?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a weird problem. At the moment I am doing a selfmade Terrain generator, for now I am doing a "plane" generation only for the bottom area with flat surface. My problem is that when I set `terrainSize` too high the triangles starts overlapping ironically.

**Here is a picture when i set `terrainSize` to 120:**
[image]

**Here is a picture when i set the `terrainSize` to 200:**

[image]

At the size 200 looks like its overlapping twice, i found out that the **max** `terrainSize` for me is **114** at 115 it starts overlapping.

Here is my code, maybe you can find something out and help me and other on this platform:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter))]
public class MeshGeneratorSecond : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private int terrainSize;

    private Mesh myMesh;
    private Vector3[] vertices;
    private int[] triangles;

    private int verticesInVertex = 5;
    private int trianglesInVertex = 4;


    void Start()
    {
        myMesh = new Mesh();
        GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = myMesh;

        vertices = new Vector3[terrainSize * terrainSize * 5];
        triangles = new int[terrainSize * terrainSize * 12];

        StartCoroutine(CreateShape());
    }

    IEnumerator CreateShape()
    {
        int vertex = 0;
        int triangle = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < terrainSize; x++)
        {
            for(int z = 0; z < terrainSize; z++)
            {
                vertices[vertex] = new Vector3(x, 0, z);
                vertices[vertex + 1] = new Vector3(x, 0, z + 1);
                vertices[vertex + 2] = new Vector3(x + 1, 0, z + 1);
                vertices[vertex + 3] = new Vector3(x + 1, 0, z);
                vertices[vertex + 4] = new Vector3(x + 0.5f, 0, z + 0.5f);

                //First Triangle
                triangles[triangle] = vertex;
                triangles[triangle + 1] = vertex + 1;
                triangles[triangle + 2] = vertex + 4;

                //Second Triangle
                triangles[triangle + 3] = vertex + 1;
                triangles[triangle + 4] = vertex + 2;
                triangles[triangle + 5] = vertex + 4;

                //Third Triangle
                triangles[triangle + 6] = vertex + 2;
                triangles[triangle + 7] = vertex + 3;
                triangles[triangle + 8] = vertex + 4;

                //Fourth Triangle
                triangles[triangle + 9] = vertex + 3;
                triangles[triangle + 10] = vertex;
                triangles[triangle + 11] = vertex + 4;

                vertex += verticesInVertex;
                triangle += trianglesInVertex * 3;
            }
            UpdateMesh();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(.1f);
        }
    }

    private void UpdateMesh()
    {
        myMesh.Clear();

        myMesh.vertices = vertices;
        myMesh.triangles = triangles;

        myMesh.RecalculateNormals();
    }
    public void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        for(int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
        {
            Gizmos.DrawSphere(vertices[i], .1f);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: In this Question here i called it area size but in my Code its the **terrainSize** variable.

Comment: Unity has a maximum vertex limit of 65535 per mesh, and due to your vertex algorithm, when you try to do your `terrainSize=115` mesh, you attempt to use 115x115x5 = 66125 vertices, which is over the limit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use meshes with more than 64k vertices in Unity 2018.1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50433894/1092820)

Comment: You may also want to look into how to re-use vertices instead of creating up to 4 vertices that all have the same position thousands of times.

Answer (score 0):

Mesh buffers are 16 bit by default. See Mesh-indexFormat:

> Index buffer can either be 16 bit (supports up to 65535 vertices in a mesh), or 32 bit (supports up to 4 billion vertices). Default index format is 16 bit, since that takes less memory and bandwidth.

Note! Ehen you want to change the 16-bit buffer to 32-bit buffer, you can change with this line of code:

```
mesh.indexFormat = UnityEngine.Rendering.IndexFormat.UInt32;
```